# es6 spread operator not combining keyed objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to build an object of keyed objects.

Why is the spread operator not combining as used below? Instead it only keeps the second object.

```js
let a = {
  key1: {
    floo: 'blar'
  }
}

let b = {
  key2: {
    floo: 'blar'
  }
}
console.log(...a, b);
```

And most importantly please show me the correct way to do this!

Thanks

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: Your code should be throwing error instead

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
console.log({...a, ...b});
```

The above will merge the two objects and will create a new object with `key1` an `key2` respectively. Also, note that spread operator for objects doesn't work the same way as [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) does.

Note that the merged object is just a reference. For example, modifying the value of the object like

```
a.key1.floo = 'someotherval';
```

will alter the `a` object and also reflect in the merged object.

For more information, refer to Spread in [Object Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Examples) section.